# Integrating Google Maps for iOS app - throws plist error

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Here's the error I get after integrating Google Maps SDK into my iOS app:

> "This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. 
>   The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data
>   2017-03-02 13:21:14.109 flightplan[27971:362149] Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places API for iOS version: 2.2.30010.0"

I then went ahead and added a `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>` and `<string>Reason</string>` in the source code of plist but it throws an error saying wrong format! Why is that?

Comment: have a look to the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26)

Comment: Can you share the piece of code?

Comment: <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> <string>Locate user's current GPS coordinates</string>

Answer (score 0):

In .plist change the key from what you made (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription) to "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description". That will do the trick.
[In Xcode, it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aeQZ.png)

Comment: <key>Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description</key>
    <string>Locate user's current GPS coordinates</string>Still the same my man.

Comment: Have you placed it to .plist using Xcode or text apps like e.g. TextEdit?

Comment: I'm asking because the XML code you pasted here won't work. As a plain text it should look like you've commented under your question:
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Your info to user</string>